# Code chunk highlighting when chunk has a pagebreak in pdf (knitr)

Tags: latex, knitr, syntax-highlighting, rnw

Here is an .Rnw file containing a random code chunk that is, when knitted to pdf, printed on two pages. I noticed that code chunk highlighting stops after a pagebreak.

1. Why is that?
2. How do I fix it?

#### The .Rnw file

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Knitr setup
<<include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
@

\begin{document}
$\;$
\vspace{15cm}
<<eval = FALSE>>=
model <- "
# Measurement models
PR =~ PR1 + PR2 + PR3
IM =~ IM1 + IM2 + IM3
DI =~ DI1 + DI2 + DI3
AD =~ AD1 + AD2 + AD3
DL =~ DL1 + DL2 + DL3
AA =~ AA1 + AA2 + AA3 + AA4 + AA5 + AA6
LO =~ LO1 + LO3
QL =~ QL1 + QL2 + QL3 + QL4 + QL5 + QL6

# Composite model for second-order construct BR
BR <~ QL + LO + AA

# Structural model
BR ~ PR + IM + DI + AD + DL 
"
@
\end{document}
```

#### Screenshot of the pagebreak with missing code highlighting after the break.

[image]

Comment: I think the first chunk should be after `\begin{document}`, or?

Comment: No it can be in the preamble.